# PHP Pagination Multiple tables? 9lessons.info theme

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, multiple-tables

I have 6 table. how to join paginagion?
Please help? TNX

I had found an example of paging entries using PHP and MySQL, which I downloaded from here. I found out that it was designed for a single table only.

Now my problem is about how to page a "mulitple queried table" (2 or more tables temporarily combined). My idea was to make a derived table from it, but it still failed.

Maybe I've done it wrong, so can someone try to help me figure out the answer. What should be my proper query?

**Table**

```
entry (entry, ent_seq)
k_ele (entry, keb)
r_ele (entry, reb)
sense (SID, entry)
s_gloss_eng (GID_eng, SID, main)
s_gloss_mn (GID_mn, SID, main_mn)
```

**My Code is**

```
<?php
$query_pag_data = 
"SELECT e.ent_seq,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sem.mean_mn SEPARATOR '; ') AS meanmn,            
sem.up_date
FROM s_gloss_mn sem
LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON sem.SID = sei.SID
LEFT JOIN sense se ON se.SID = sem.SID
LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON kei.entry = se.entry
LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON rei.entry = kei.entry
LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.entry = rei.entry
WHERE sem.up_date 
GROUP BY e.entry
ORDER BY sem.up_date DESC";

$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$finaldata = "";
$tablehead="<tr>
<td width='8%'>ID</td>
<td width='20%'>Word</td>
<td width='20%'>Hiragana</td>
<td width='22%'>English</td>
<td width='25%'>Mongolia</td>
<td width='5%'>Edit</td>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $id=$row['ent_seq'];
    $kanji=$row['kebs'];
    $readings=$row['rebs'];
    $mean_eng=$row['means'];
    $mean_mn=$row['meanmn'];

$tabledata.="<tr id='$id' class='edit_tr_wc'>

<td class='edit_td_wc' >
    <span id='five_$id' class='text_wc'>$id</span>
    <input type='text' value='$id' class='editbox_wc' id='five_input_$id' />
</td>

<td class='edit_td_wc' >
    <span id='one_$id' class='text_wc'>$kanji</span>
    <input type='text' value='$kanji' class='editbox_wc' id='one_input_$id' />
</td>

<td class='edit_td_wc' >
    <span id='two_$id' class='text_wc'>$readings</span> 
    <input type='text' value='$readings' class='editbox_wc' id='two_input_$id'/>
</td>

<td class='edit_td_wc' >
    <span id='three_$id' class='text_wc'>$mean_eng</span> 
    <input type='text' value='$mean_eng' class='editbox_wc' id='three_input_$id'/>
</td>

<td class='edit_td_wc' >
    <span id='four_$id' class='text_wc'>$mean_mn</span> 
    <input type='text' value='$mean_mn' class='editbox_wc' id='four_input_$id'/>
</td>

<td><a href='#' class='Add' id='$id'> ADD </a>
</tr>";}

$finaldata = "<table width='100%' class='edit_wc'>". $tablehead . $tabledata ."</table>"; //     Content for Data

/* Total Count */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM s_gloss_mn";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
?>
```

Comment: The number of tables shouldn't matter. Pagination is done the same way.